# What's wrong here? (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: objective-c

My app crashes during when it tries to round some numbers down. What could be the problem?
The debugger shows the first line causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
- (NSInteger) hebrewCalanderEndDay:(NSInteger)year{

NSInteger monthsElapsed = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:floor((235*year-234)/19.0)]integerValue];
NSInteger partsElapsed = 12084 + 13753*monthsElapsed;
NSInteger day = 29*monthsElapsed + [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:floor(partsElapsed/25920)] integerValue];

if(((3 * (day+1))%7 <3){
  day++;
} 
return day;
}
```

Comment: You seriously couldn't just copy the code and paste it here? Or is your Mac not able to get online so you're writing from your iPhone (judging from that yfrog link)?

Comment: Mac is offline. I would have typed it out. My only internet is my iPhone.

Comment: @Moshe: That's alright, I've edited your question. Does your carrier not support 3G tethering? I tether when my wi-fi dies.

Comment: My carrier charges extra. I don't pay for it. Thank you. I typed it too. I'll roll back.

Comment: @deceze @Moshe Man, that's a lot of editing going on.

Comment: Are you sure the app is crashing in that part of the code? Aside from NSNumber being misspelled in the third line (should be NSNumber not NSnumber but I assume that has to do with a transcription error since that wouldn't compile) that code is fine and there's no real way you should be able to get a bad access in that section.

Comment: @Mattia after that it goes into low level functions in the private API.

Comment: What's curious is that you're using `NSNumber` objects in converting from integers to long longs and back.

Comment: How about not do that? The usage of NSNumber here is completely spurious, and provides absolutely nothing. It could just as easily be replaced with a cast to `(NSInteger)`. Even weirder is the fact that you're passing a float into `+numberWithLongLong:` despite that method taking, obviously, a `long long`.

Comment: Actually, it's a double. But yea, let ne try casting it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I see is a type mismatch between `floor()` and `+numberWithLongLong:`.  Didn't the compiler complain about that?

Are you trying to implement the Hebrew calendar yourself?  I thought that CFLocale already supported it.

Comment: Nope that's not the issue. Discussib in the Tavern on MSO chat

Comment: That's true. I didn't know that though. Going to try to use that.